# How to write $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\left(\frac{1}5\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to write $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\left(\frac{1}5\right)$

I mean the sum is $0$ if $k$ is even and $1/5$ otherwise, but I want to write it in one line, is it possible, wolframalpha delivers $\frac{-1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\left((-1)^k-1\right)$, but how did it get that ?

Answer (score 2):

$(-1)^k$ is $1$ if $k$ is even and $-1$ if $k$ is odd, so $(-1)^k-1$ is $0$ if $k$ is even and $-2$ if $k$ is odd. Multiply that by $\frac12$, and you find that

$$\frac12\big((-1)^k-1\big)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }k\text{ is even}\\
-1,&\text{if }k\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Thus, no matter what $x$ is,

$$\frac12x\big((-1)^k-1\big)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }k\text{ is even}\\
-x,&\text{if }k\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

In particular, if $x=-\frac15$, you get the desired result.

Comment: So how did Wolfram|Alpha get it?

Comment: @quid: How would I know? If you mean this particular way of expressing the odd/even oscillation, it’s standard enough to be built in, but for all I know it gets there by some other route.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott yes if one knows the result then it is easier to check the correctness, but is this a well known result, I mean does it have a name like "negative indicator function" or so?

Comment: @ketum: Not that I know of. It’s just a standard trick for writing an expression whose value depends predictably on the parity of some integer.

Comment: I don't know. But that is part of the question.

Comment: Even if not built in as a special case, $$\sum_{j = 0}^{k-1} (-1)^j = \frac{1 - (-1)^k}{1-(-1)}$$ by the formula for geometric sums. To find out which way W|A uses, we'd need somebody with access to the software.

Comment: @quid: Only if the question was meant literally, which is possible but by no means clear.

Comment: @Daniel: That seems the likeliest possibility, unless the software is designed to recognize periodic functions on the integers and deal with them as a family.

Comment: If the question is not clear to you, you should not answer it.

Comment: @quid: I’ve 40 years’ experience interpreting questions, and on the evidence I’m good at it. I’m willing to take the chance of occasionally being wrong.

Comment: I recall you arguing on other occasions for one should take questions literally (even if they make little sense that way, which is not even the case in this case). Of course today is another day.